# How to get load more spinner while using infinite-scrolling in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I can't get it to work. I am trying to show 10 items at once when scrolling down *(so initially 10 and after scrolling, again 10 new items)*, while using `ng-repeat` and this works, but a load more spinner isn't working for me. Whatever I do, I can't show it.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="schedule in Schedules | filter:scheduleSearch | limitTo:numberOfItemsToDisplay | orderBy: 'namesAlphabet' as names">
    Display some data
</li> 
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="addMoreItem()" ng-if="Schedules.length > numberOfItemsToDisplay"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**My controller:**

```
$scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 10; // Use it with limit to in ng-repeat
$scope.addMoreItem = function(done) {
    if ($scope.Schedules.length > $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay)
        $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 10; // load number of more items
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete')
}
```

How can I do this? Is there a way to bind the scrolling to an icon?

Comment: Check ionic.app.css contain these lines `code ion-infinite-scroll .icon {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #666666; }
  ion-infinite-scroll:not(.active) .spinner,
  ion-infinite-scroll:not(.active) .icon:before {
    display: none; }`

Comment: Yes, but what does that mean? How can I implement it?

Comment: @Siyah do you mean that the item is loaded as it is using `ion-infinite-scroll` but the load more spinner is not showing?

Comment: Exactly @whyyie. Items are being loaded, but it just happens... they are just loaded, but I don't see any indicator that it is being loaded (no spinner, no loading icon, nothing). They are just being added, that's all.

Comment: @Siyah does the answer i provide below help you resolve the issue or it still does not work as expected?

Comment: @whyyie: I didn't see your answer. I'll check asap and let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the item is loaded too fast that the `infiniteScrollComplete` is being broadcasted before the loading icon is shown.

If you insist to have the loading icon to be shown in such situation, add a `$timeout` to it.

```
$scope.addMoreItem = function(done) {
    $timeout(function() {
        if ($scope.Schedules.length > $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay)
            $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 10; // load number of more items
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete')
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, whyyie. The list items in the ng-repeat are ordered in a certain way. I noticed that when I use this snippet, it messes up the way the list items are ordered (the ones that should be shown last, are shown first and are going back to their place after loading other items).... Is there a way to keep the order / hierarchy?

Comment: Beside that, it's not working properly, because it initially shows (let's say 4 items) and after 2 seconds, it directly shows me all others, while I haven't scrolled yet?! That shouldn't be happening, right? I want them to be queried AFTER scrolling.

Comment: @Siyah could you reproduce it into a full code sample? and does the spinner came out?

Comment: thanks, the spinner works. I have added the "order by" in the original snippet so that you can check. If we can fix that, it would be wonderful.

Comment: @Siyah i think its better for you to open another post for this. 1) The issue of spinner has been resolved as per title. 2) Adding `$timeout` wouldn't affect the outcome of the list as the code structure still remains the same unless there is logic issue with the original code you posted.

Comment: Thanks mate, will open a new one for this.